# Using German umlaut in LaTeX tabular directive

Tags: tables, input-encodings

I am trying to use German umlauts in a tabular directive. The file is encoded in UTF8 and the useage of umlauts outside of the tabular directive is working flawlessly so there should be no general encoding problem.

Using the following code

```
\begin{tabular}{ll}
  some content & some content ü content \\
\end{tabular}
```

the compiler issues the following warning:

```
Package inputenc Error: Keyboard character used is undefined [& some content]
```

It seems the compiler is interpreting the characters following the ampersand as an escaped unicode character. In the PDF output the umlaut is simply omitted.

Is there a possibility to either escape the umlaut, change the encoding of the tabular section or use a different character for column separation?

Encoding the umlaut using escaped unicode or \"u is not working due to both ampersand and backslash being control characters.

I am no LaTeX expert and desperately need this functionality for my bachelor thesis. My lifelong gratitude will truly be yours.

**EDIT**

I use the following in my head section, my distribution is MiXTeX 2.9 using Sublime Text 2 as my editor. My operating system is Windows 7 Professional x64

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, titlepage]{book}
\usepackage{german}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

**EDIT2**

I had no encoding problem and just discovered, that even though regular TeX escaping in the form of

```
\"u
```

wont work, surrounding this with curly braces will

```
{\"u}
```

for now this answer justifies using UTF8 instead of latin1 encoding but if anybody knows a more elegant solution I would be keen on your input!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/5764) Your question was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: Please check wether you have an up-to-date installation (with current package versions, see MikTeX Console.)
In addition, please note that you probably want to use the package ngerman instead of german, which supports only old orthography. 
Are the ü's displayed correctly when you are using TeXWorks?
LG von einem deutschen LaTeX-Nutzer. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Please try :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lll}
  some content \& some content ü content \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

If that does not show the expected result, please check your TeX installation (**texlive-latex-extra** may be of help then).

Comment: thank you for the fast reply! using your method, I get the following error: Package inputenc Error: Keyboard character used is undefined [some content \& some content ]

Comment: Than the problem may be that your input file itself is not properly utf8 encoded. Have you checked that ?

Comment: The encoding of input files hasn't been the issue. I found a solution using curly brace based escaping. Inspite of this I will try TeXLive. Thank you both for the input :-)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/5764) Your answer was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or edit your answer.